# How to detect diagonal win in "5 in a row" game (PHP)

Tags: php, algorithm

I have to write a nice little "5 in a row" game. I have successfully detected row and column wins like this:

For rows:

```
$same=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$size;$i++) for($j=1;$j<=$size;$j++){ /wins in a row
        if((@$_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j] == @$_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j+1]) && @$_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j]!=0 ) ++$same; else $same=0;
        if($same==4){
            if($_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j]==1) $winner="First"; //will be read from DB
            if($_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j]==2) $winner="Second"; //will be read from DB
            print $winner.' player WON!<br />';  
        }
}
```

For columns, it's the same but the other way around, so that was easy. Now my question is, how do you detect diagonal wins? I tried to search for it, but I couldn't find anything I could have used (or understood). I'm only allowed to use PHP.

```
What is what:
$same = same symbol counter
$_SESSION["pos"][$i][$j] = the 2D array of coordinates of the board (starting from 1,1 not 0,0)
indexes are the coordinates, values can be 0 (empty space) or 1 (symbol1) or 2 (symbol2)
$size = size of the board (always N x N)
```

You don't have to spoonfeed me a complete code, I just need something to understand how to do it.

Comment: These lecturers are getting very imaginative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let our game area have width of 5. It's kind of tricky or hack, but we can work with such array as a long string and find substrings like `XXXXX`, or `00000` (for row check), or `X....{5 times}` (for column check) or  `X.....{5 times}` (for \ diagonal check) and `X...{5 times}` for / diagonal.

So we just need to replace `.` with any symbol and find such patterns. This task is when we can use regular expressions. We just need to match that patterns with [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

I don't know the way quicker but it seems to be original (example just for `X` check):

```
<?php
$area = array(
    array('x','x','x','x','x'),
    array('0','0','x','x','0'),
    array('x','x','x','x','0'),
    array('0','0','x','x','x'),
    array('x','0','x','0','x'),
    );

//get the long string of that array
$fullstring = '';
foreach($area as $string) {
    $fullstring .= implode('', $string)."|";
}

//check long string for such patterns
$win_by_column = preg_match('/x.{5}x.{5}x.{5}x.{5}x/i', $fullstring); //5 game area width
$win_by_row = preg_match('/x{5}/i', $fullstring); //5 same in rows
$win_by_bs_diagonal = preg_match('/x.{6}x.{6}x.{6}x.{6}x/i', $fullstring); // \ diagonal, 5 is $area width + 1
$win_by_s_diagonal = preg_match('/x.{4}x.{4}x.{4}x.{4}x/i', $fullstring); // / diagonal, 4 is $area width - 1.

//output the results
var_dump($win_by_column);
var_dump($win_by_row);
var_dump($win_by_bs_diagonal);
var_dump($win_by_s_diagonal);
?>
```

This is also a good start if you are not familiar with regular expressions ;)

**UPD.** I've updated the code. I insert string separator in array string. So now we need to check 5 dots (any symbols) in column check and 6 at diagonal check. This hardcoded values calculated as width and width+1 accordingly. For the simlicity of reading and understanding I not insert `$area` width in patterns.

Comment: I just had to change the X-es to my symbols, and use a variable for the area size, and it detects the diagonal 5s perfectly.
Thank you!

Comment: I change your `4-check` to `5-check` for the simplicity in this example. I believe that if you will use `4-check` you will also need to check 2-side uncloseness for row, column and diagonal. Good question!

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, it will incorrectly detect wrapped rows like the 5 `x`'s in (row 1: `0xxxx`, row 2: `x0000`). The same problem would also affect diagonals if the board was larger (and it's the reason why your simpler `/` diagonal check doesn't work). To fix it, you could add a separator character between the rows (and increase the offsets in the regexps by one).

Comment: Diagonal check worked because of hardcoded 5 means game area width, not 5 in row.

Comment: With the change, you could now also get rid of the `$fullstring_rev` variable and just match `/x.{4}x.{4}x.{4}x.{4}x/` against `$fullstring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect diagonals the same way as you detect rows and columns: just treat a diagonal as a slanted row (or column).  That is, instead of looking at cell `[$i][$j]`, look at `[$i+$j][$j]` (for diagonals with positive slant) or `[$i-$j][$j]` (for negative slant).

For example, here's how you could detect negative diagonals:

```
$grid = $_SESSION["pos"];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) {
    $same = 0;
    $prev = 0;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $size && $i-$j >= 1; $j++) {
        $cur = @$grid[$i-$j][$j];
        if ($cur == $prev && $cur != 0) ++$same;
        else $same = 0;
        if ($same == 4) {
            $winner = ($cur == 1 ? "First" : "Second"); //will be read from DB
            print "$winner player WON!<br />";  
        }
        $prev = $cur;
    }
}
```

Changing this to check positive diagonals is left as an exercise.

Comment: Now that I see the solution it's easier than I thought. I just couldn't figure it out by myself. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check diagonal by two separate for loop:

```
$area = array(
    array('x','x','x','x','x'),
    array('0','x','x','x','0'),
    array('x','x','x','x','0'),
    array('0','x','x','x','x'),
    array('x','0','x','0','x'),
);

$diagonal1 = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){

   if($area[$i][$i] == 'x'){
       $diagonal1 ++;
   }
}

if($diagonal1 == 5){
    echo 'Diagonal win';
}

// other diagonal
$diagonal2 = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){

    if($area[$i][4 - $i] == 'x'){
        $diagonal2 ++;
    }
}

if($diagonal2 == 5){
    echo 'Diagonal win';
}
```

Comment: This is good if we have "5 * 5" board, but my board is "n * n" so checking only the two main diagonals is not enough. Thanks for your answer thought.

Comment: Yes, but if your board is square, then you can calculate number to iterate in for loop and check it dynamicly.