# Finding 5 values in a row diagonally in Java

Tags: java

I have this 10x10 array:

```
private static int[][] intersections = new int[10][10];
```

I'm using this code to find if there are 5 values in a row horizontally:

```
public static int horizontalCheck() {
    String horizontal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < intersections[i].length; j++) {
            horizontal += Integer.toString(intersections[i][j]);
        }
        if (horizontal.indexOf("11111") != -1) {
            // White wins.
            return 1;
        } else if (horizontal.indexOf("22222") != -1) {
            // Black wins.
            return 2;
        }
        horizontal = "";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And a similar code to do it vertically. But my question is, how could I find if there are 5 values in a row diagonally? The board is sized 10x10 and the diagonals can be both ways anywhere on the board. If you have any questions or need some more information on the code, make sure to ask.

Comment: what does this mean ? 5 values in a row horizontally.

Comment: i think using `horizontal.contains` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: If you know php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316090/how-to-detect-diagonal-win-in-5-in-a-row-game-php

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Basically what I mean, is that it is a Gomoku game, where you win on having 5 buttons in a row either horizontally, vertically or diagonally. The player buttons are represented in the array accordingly as 1 and 2.

Comment: Small point. Regardless to strange algorithm for intersections, you shouldn't use string concatenation if it runs many times. It is deadly ineffective. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you write a helper function for this. The function should take these parameters:

- `r0` - The starting row from which the check needs to start
- `c0` - The starting column from which the check needs to start
- `dr` - The vertical step from `{-1, 0, 1}`
- `dc` - The horizontal step from `{-1, 0, 1}`
- `len` - The number of items to be found
- `num` - The number to find.

Here is how this function may look:

```
private static boolean checkRow(int r0, int c0, int dr, int dc, int len, int num) {
    for (int k = 0 ; k != len ; k++) {
        int r = r0 + k*dr;
        int c = c0 + k*dc;
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= intersections.length || c > intersections[r].length || intersections[r][c] != num) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

With this function in hand, you can check for `len` items in a row in any direction that you wish:

```
// See if we've got five eights in any direction:
for (int r = 0 ; r != intersections.length ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0 ; c != intersections[r].length ; c++) {
        if (checkRow(r, c, 0, 1, 5, 8)) {
            System.out.println("Horizontal, starting at "+r+" " +c);
        }
        if (checkRow(r, c, 1, 0, 5, 8)) {
            System.out.println("Vertical, starting at "+r+" " +c);
        }
        if (checkRow(r, c, 1, 1, 5, 8)) {
            System.out.println("Diagonal descending right, starting at "+r+" " +c);
        }
        if (checkRow(r, c, 1, -1, 5, 8)) {
            System.out.println("Diagonal descending left, starting at "+r+" " +c);
        }
    }
}
```