# Console-based Connect Four game - diagonal win checker algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm more or less new to Java.

I'm making a console-based connect 4 game in java and I'm pretty much done, I'm just struggling with how to check for a diagonal win (four pieces in a row diagonally). My vertical/horizontal win checkers are working fine, but I can't figure out how to do a similar thing for a diagonal-checker. The board is a 2d-array which is printed to the console, and to check for a win, I check for four of the same piece next to each other or above each other.

Here are the bits of board code:

```
private String board[][] = new String[8][8];
```

creates array

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "( )";
        }
    }
```

fills the board with blank slots

```
void displayBoard() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And here is the winchecker

```
boolean winCheck1() {
    String p = "(" + piece1 + ")";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if ((board[i][j].equals(p) && board[i][j + 1].equals(p)
                    && board[i][j + 2].equals(p) && board[i][j + 3]
                    .equals(p))) {
                this.win1();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if ((board[j][i].equals(p) && board[j + 1][i].equals(p)
                    && board[j + 2][i].equals(p) && board[j + 3][i]
                    .equals(p))) {
                this.win1();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    this.play2();
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385019/finding-5-values-in-a-row-diagonally-in-java#comment30437415_20385019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep doing it your way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if ((board[j][i].equals(p) && board[j + 1][i + 1].equals(p)
                && board[j + 2][i + 2].equals(p) && board[j + 3][i + 3]
                .equals(p))) {
            this.win1();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 3; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if ((board[j][i].equals(p) && board[j + 1][i - 1].equals(p)
                && board[j + 2][i - 2].equals(p) && board[j + 3][i - 3]
                .equals(p))) {
            this.win1();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's probably better to do this with loops (iterate over directions).